# Inject JavaScript on iFrame to get virtual keyboard functionality

Tags: javascript, frontend, virtual-keyboard

Is it possible to inject our own JavaScript in the iFrame on a external domain ex) xyz.com ? (The original objective is to get the Virtual Keyboard functionality working on an iFrame that has a link to an external webapp.